# How to switch into <DIV> inside another <DIV>s in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on a button which is inside nested DIVs.
 Below is the html

```
<div class="chat-message-container ngi bot" chat-msg-id="EzPtItD3exi2lTGS3SQkV0-h|0000016" chat-msg-text="What is the intended purpose of your investment">
            <div class="message-bubble">

                <div class="message-text"><p>What is the intended purpose of your investment</p>
                </div>
                >
            </div>
            <div class="attachment-container">
        <div id="0attachment" style="display: block" class="attachment">
            <div class="attachment-info">
                <div class="attachment-title"></div>
                <p class="attachment-subtitle-1"></p>
                <p class="attachment-subtitle-2"></p>
                <div class="carousel-counter-container">
                    <button type="button" id="0prev" class="carousel-btn-ngi" data-atura-carousel="prev">&lt;</button>
                    <p class="carousel-counter" }"="">1/1</p>
                    <button type="button" id="0next" class="carousel-btn-ngi" data-atura-carousel="next">&gt;</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="action-button-container"><a href="0 - 3 years" class="link-as-button quick-reply" data-instant-message-reply-ngi="" data-button-display-value="0 - 3 years">0 - 3 years</a><a href="3 - 5 years" class="link-as-button quick-reply" data-instant-message-reply-ngi="" data-button-display-value="3 - 5 years">3 - 5 years</a><a href="over 5 years" class="link-as-button quick-reply" data-instant-message-reply-ngi="" data-button-display-value="over 5 years">over 5 years</a>
            </div>
        </div></div>
        </div>
```

I need to click on button 0 - 3 years

I have tried to click the elemet using xpath as below
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='0attachment']/div[2]/a[1]")).click();

it did not work. I think it is because of the nested structure. I read about the switch method. But i dont think that can be used to switch inside another DIV

Kindly help

Comment: See: [How do I do X?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253069/whats-the-appropriate-new-current-close-reason-for-how-do-i-do-x) The expectation on SO is that the user asking a question not only does research to answer their own question but also shares that research, code attempts, and results. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks Ahmed. I am trying to post the HTML. When I edit the post I can see the whole information. But when I post it, the code and the information I give below the code is missing

Comment: What have you tried so far and what is the result of that? Is there any error/exception? If there is then post the error also.

Comment: Hi Ahmed, I managed to post the complete info. I have trid to find the element by xpath. but selenium failied to identify the element. I dont think I can use switch as I am not switching into a frame.

Comment: It should throw an exception. Like `NoSuchElement` or `ElementNotClickable`. Do you get any exception?

Comment: yes Ahmed. I got no such element exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `click()` on the element with text as **0 - 3 years** need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "0 - 3 years"))).click()
  ```
- Using `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "0 - 3 years"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.action-button-container>a.link-as-button.quick-reply[data-button-display-value='0 - 3 years']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='action-button-container']/a[@class='link-as-button quick-reply' and contains(., '0 - 3 years')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you. I am going to try these options. Will let you know shortly

Comment: Thanks you Debanjan. As soon as I changed the xpath from @id='0attachment']/div[2]/a[1] to what you have suggested, it worked like a charm. If you don't mind, i need a favour. I use chrome object inspector (right click and copy->xpath) to find the xpath of the element. Could you please point me to any article which I can go through to form the xpath as you have suggested.    Even the cssselector from chrome is #\30 attachment > div.action-button-container > a:nth-child(1) which obviously does not find the element